# How do I iterate over a list of IPs, usernames, and passwords to establish multiple ssh connections?

Tags: python, loops

I am working on writing a program that can establish an ssh connection and write the output of a couple of commands to a file. My code can currently do this for one computer.

I would like it to iterate over a list of IP addresses, usernames, and passwords I have saved to a userinfo file, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. Here is the current code I have for assigning values to ip, username, and password:

```
import userinfo

port = 22
ip = userinfo.host
user = userinfo.username
passwd = userinfo.password
```

Any help or advice in rewriting this troubled code is appreciated!

Comment: You're facing an issue at which step?

Comment: Do not call `str()` on things that are already strings.

Comment: Are you having an issues at retrieving data from in my assumption a txt file or the iteration process to store all the values?

Comment: The `parallel-ssh` and `clusterssh` tools can both do this out of the box.  No programming needed.

Comment: My issue is that this only lets me execute the program for one system, I would like it to execute for multiple systems using information from the userinfo file. 
I'm not having trouble retrieving the data, but trouble iterating over multiple username/password/IP combos

Comment: Can you please share more code?